# Telerik MVC Grid Inline editing requires page refresh to display changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a Telerik MVC Grid where I am updating the rows inline (updating name column, number column is uneditable)

```
 @Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Employees)
        .Name("EmployeeGrid")
        .Columns(col =>
        {
            col.Bound(o => o.EmployeeNumber);
            col.Bound(o => o.Name).Width(250);
            col.Command(command => { command.Edit(); });
        })
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Events(e => e.RequestEnd("onGridDataSourceRequestEnd"))
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(o => o.EmployeeNumber);
            model.Field(o => o.EmployeeNumber).Editable(false);
        })
        .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Update", "EmployeeUpdate"))
        .ServerOperation(false)
        )
        .Render();


 function onGridDataSourceRequestEnd(e) {
    if (e.type == "update") {
        console.log('I am inside Update');
        $("#EmployeeGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
    }
}
```

My problem is that above code updates the record by calling action EmployeeUpdate when I click on Update button in the grid. However, that change doesnt immediately reflect in the grid even though I am calling datasource read in JS function. Console shows "I am inside Update" but doesnt refresh grid. If I refresh the page, I do see the update row.

Please let me know what am I missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have to refresh/reload your grid when doing an update, you just have to return the updated record from the controller and grid-widget will take care of the rest!

Please checkout telerik [demo-page](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-inline)

The most common error I do is forgetting to return a datasourceresult:

```
.ToDataSourceResult(request,ModelState)
```

Telerik normally returns the same model that are sent in to the update, but I normally returns the same object that the read function returns (if read does something I'll get that on the updated record too).

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should try refreshing the grid with [`refresh()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-refresh) function:

```
function onGridDataSourceRequestEnd(e) {
    if (e.type == "update") {
        console.log('I am inside Update');
        $("#EmployeeGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();

        // add this line
        $("#EmployeeGrid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
    }
}
```

Note that [`read()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/read) function in `dataSource` only reload data source by request to the server, the grid contents still not changed before using `refresh()`.